# How do I create a new database using C# code in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.Net web forms application connected to a SQL Server Database 'Db_1'.

Now, there is a button of which button click event, there will be some calculations, then create a new database 'Db_2' and store the results in the new database 'Db_2'.

How do I create the database 'Db_2'?

Comment: By executing the [CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command connected to `master` database.

Comment: Depending on what level of control you need SMO might be the prefered way. In any case there are already a lot of questions and answers that should cover most aspects.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the below [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) code to create the database.

```cs
// Creating instance of SqlConnection  
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(".........");  
conn.Open();// open the database connection  
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();// Creating instance of SqlCommand  
cmd.Connection = conn; // set the connection to instance of SqlCommand  
cmd.CommandText = "Create database Db_2"; // set  
//the sql command ( Statement )  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
conn.Close();// Close the connection
```

Once database is create you need to create an another steps to create the table and insert the data into that table using same ADO.NET process with different SQL Server command like `create table()` and `insert into table values ()`.

For the steps involved in two and three, you need to create and use another instance of the newly created database.

Comment: ... and most importantly change the connection to use the new database first.

Comment: @Opengenic Although, thank you comment is not promoted by SO community. See, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).